# Database or website of kernel config files?

Tags: configuration, hardware, kernel, gentoo

I've experienced some kernel panic after trying to compile gentoo kernel for a Sun UltraSPARC T5120 Server. The kernel panic came from a missing support for the SAS disk controller in the menu config. I've wasted so much time because I had no clue about the hardware I was using.

I know that the kernel config depends on what you plan to do with your machine but I want to have a configuration file that at least match my hardware !

Is there a website or database that provides menuconfig's kernel configuration files for known or branded hardware like Dell Server or Apple computers ?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  There might be something out run by someone, but I don't know of any such sites off the top of my head.

If you're running on Sun hardware, just look up the system specs to ID the SAS controller in the box, and then look for that driver in Linux's 'menuconfig' under 'Device Drivers' --> 'SCSI device support' --> 'Low-level drivers'

Being that it is SPARC, and you've tagged this question with 'gentoo', you can also drop into #gentoo-sparc on the Freenode IRC network and see if anyone there can assist you with that specific hardware.